# Compare collection of integers

Tags: java, compare

For an implementation of [`Comparable<>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) I am looking for a way to compare two instances of `Collection<boolean[]>`. I am already comparing the `boolean[]`'s by creating an integer representation (101 == 5) so I've narrowed it down to comparing two `Collection<Integer>`'s.

How would I go about doing this?

Simply comparing each integer does not work because given `collectionA = {1, 2}; collectionB = {2,1}`, the following example gives `cmp == 0`, while the collections are certainly different.

```
int cmp = 0;
for(Integer a : collectionA)
  for(Integer b : collectionB)
    cmp += Integer.compare(a, b);
```

What other options do I have? I don't really care *how* they are sorted, just *that* they are sorted in a consisting manner. The collections may have different sizes.

Edit:
I am really looking for a `int compare()`, not an `equals()`. A more concrete example with the actual structure of my application looks like this

```
class MyArray implements Comparable<MyArray> {
    boolean[] array;

    int compareTo(MyArray another) {
        // This is implemented
    }
}

class MyCollection implements Comparable<MyCollection> {
    SortedSet<MyArray> collection;

    int compareTo(MyCollection another) {
        // Looking for this implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: Java Collections have no specific order, so it does not make sense to claim that {1,2} is not equal to {2,1}. First of all, *you* must make a decision what it means for you that two collections are equal. This is not defined by the Java API.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.  What are the input requirements?  Does the order of the collections matter (it appears so)?  i.e. Are you sorting a collection of arrays where the order matters?

Comment: I don't understand well.. {1,2} is greater or lower than {2,1}? What are the rules applied?

Comment: I don't care if comparing {1,2} and {2,1} gives me a positive or a negative number, I should just not return 0;

Comment: Are you sure you need a "Collection<boolean[]>": collection of boolean arrays ? It sounds extra-weird.

Comment: The `boolean[]`'s are always of the same size, the `Collection<boolean[]>`'s are not, that is why I chose this construction.

Comment: Until you specify what you want the compareTo function to return, no one can answer this question.

Comment: If third-party libraries are legit, you can get a `Comparator<Iterable<boolean[]>>` (which will work for `Collection`s) in [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) with the one line `Ordering.from(Booleans.lexicographicalComparator()).lexicographical()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare your lists the same way strings are compared: first compare the first integers, if they are equal, check the second integers, etc until you find different integers or you reach the end of the list.

```
for(int i = 0; i < min(listA.size(), listB.size()); i++) {
    int diff = listA.get(i) - listB.get(i);
    if(diff != 0) return diff;
}
return listA.size() - listB.size();
```

Note that this works only if your collections are ordered.

Comment: this works only if list are sorted the same way, but I think that he means that sorting of the list should not harm the compare.

Comment: @holap no, Joost says that {1, 2} and {2, 1} should be different.

Comment: you're right, he confused me when he asserted "I don't really care how they are sorted". Well, waiting for more details.

Comment: Upvoted. I would just test listB.size() != listA.size() at beginning not in the end.

Comment: @holap that's a possibility, in that case {1, 2, 3} would be "bigger" than {3, 2}.

Comment: Joost's question still doesn't make sense, so answering it is impossible. As I commented on his question, Collections are *not* ordered in Java, so working with Collections and demanding an order dependent behaviour of some functionality is simply not possible.

Comment: @jarnbjo you’re right, in this answer I’m assuming that his collections are actually lists.

Comment: @WilQu; Thanks this solutions works. I did change the .get(i) to something with iterators to make it work for Collections rather than lists. They actually are SortedSets
@jarnbjo; I am not sorting the Collection itself, I want to sort several collections, eg TreeSet<Collection<Stuff>>, or as seen in my example `TreeSet<MyCollection>`

Comment: @Joost, if your collections are not ordered, your question does not make sense as jarnbjo said, and this solution will not work.

Comment: Okay, You guys are right that I have overdone the abstracting of the implementation. I'll make sure `MyCollection` references a `SortedSet` rather than a `Collection`

Answer (score 1):

The built in equals() method in the java collections classes will already do this for you.

They return true if both collections are the same size and for each element in one collection there is a corresponding element in the other.

The `List` comparison checks order, but if you use a `Set` instead then it does not care about the order.

**List**

> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if (e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).) In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the List interface.

**Set**

> Compares the specified object with this set for equality. Returns true if the specified object is also a set, the two sets have the same size, and every member of the specified set is contained in this set (or equivalently, every member of this set is contained in the specified set). This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the set interface.

Comment: I am not looking for a equality test. I need my Collections sorted, eg `TreeSet<Collection<Integer>>`

Comment: Even if List#equal and Set#equal are well defined, the question here is about how to compare two Collections (which are not necessarily Lists or Sets).

Comment: There is no such way, since the concept of 'comparison' isn't defined by your question.

Comment: Well I did mention the implementation of Comparable<>... Even with link to the docs